# NumPyArrayToTable - RuntimeError: unsupported time units. use M8[us]

Tags: arcpy, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe (df) to a table in a file geodatabase using code below:

```
records = df.to_records(index=False)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(records,r'C:\TEST.gdb\records')
```

Error message:

> RuntimeError: unsupported time units. use M8[us]

Using `df.dtypes` I can see that my date fields are type `datetime64[ns]`:

```
>>df.dtypes

field1              float64
field2              float64
field3              object
field4              float64
field5          datetime64[ns]
...
```

So I guess I need to change the type from `datetime64[ns]` to `M8[us`]. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Playing around with dates using `numpy`, `pandas`, and `arcpy` tools for writing `numpy` arrays into geodatabase tables can be challenging.

I usually use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` in favor of `arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable` just because I get a more fine grained control over the data types. The performance of `InsertCursor` is great, you will be able to write millions of records in minutes.

Something like this:

```
# create a feature class
#...
# add fields from df.columns
#...

rows_to_write = [tuple(r[1:]) for r in df.itertuples()] 
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_fc,df.columns) as ins_cur:
    for row in rows_to_write:
        ins_cur.insertRow(row)
```

However, if you do need to use `arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable`, here is the code that will work:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.version.full_version)
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)

from datetime import datetime
data = [(1,datetime(2011, 1, 2)), (2,datetime(2011, 1, 5)), (3,datetime(2011, 1, 7))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['RowId','RowDate'])
print(df)
#   RowId    RowDate
#0      1 2011-01-02
#1      2 2011-01-05
#2      3 2011-01-07

#for pandas 0.17 (ArcGIS Pro 1.3 Python)
#in_array = np.array([(r.RowId,np.datetime64(r.RowDate)) for r in df.itertuples()],
                    #np.dtype([('CustomId', '<i8'),
                              #('CustomDate', 'M8[us]')]))

#for pandas 0.16 (ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 Python)
in_array = np.array([(r[1],np.datetime64(r[2])) for r in df.itertuples()],
                    np.dtype([('CustomId', '<i8'),
                              ('CustomDate', 'M8[us]')]))

print(in_array)
#array([(1, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 2, 0, 0)),
#   (2, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 5, 0, 0)),
#   (3, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 7, 0, 0))], 
#  dtype=[('CustomId', '<i8'), ('CustomDate', '<M8[us]')])

import arcpy
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(in_array,r'C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\records_pandas')
```

You won't be able to use the `df.to_records()` because you will lose the `numpy` types. You have to construct a `numpy.array` manually before feeding it to the `arcpy` function.

To verify the contents:

```
print([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(r'C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\records_pandas')])
for i in [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\records_pandas',"*")]:
    print(i)

['OBJECTID', 'CustomId', 'CustomDate']
(1, 1, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 2, 0, 0))
(2, 2, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 5, 0, 0))
(3, 3, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 7, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently encountered the same issue. This approach worked on my dataframe (ArcGIS Pro 2.9, python 3.7, pandas 1.2.3) and didn't require knowing the field names or types. Hopefully this is more broadly applicable.

```py
import pandas as pd
# Assuming you have a pandas dataframe named 'df'
# list data types
list_dtypes = [i.str for i in df.dtypes]

# turn object type into 255 character string type
# turn datetimes type into M8[us] type
list_dtypes = ['<U255'  if d == '|O'      else d for d in list_dtypes]
list_dtypes = ['M8[us]' if d == '<M8[ns]' else d for d in list_dtypes]

# format as list of tuples (field name and adjusted dtype)
tup_dtypes =  [(f,t) for f,t in zip(list(df.columns.values),list_dtypes)]

# write to array, recasting the to_records array with .astype()
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(df.to_records(index=False).astype(tup_dtypes),r"tablepath")
```